# Ejercicio generar contraseña aleatoria

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito ayuda con un ejercicio de Python3

> Usando módulos resuelva el siguiente problema:
>
> Una empresa desea crear contraseñas seguras para las cuentas de acceso al sistema de sus empleados, para ello se desea generar una contraseña que tenga en cuenta ciertos requerimientos. Se recomienda crear las siguientes funciones:
>
> - GenerarPassword(): genera una contraseña (cadena) aleatoria con una longitud
>     de 10. (20 puntos)
> - esFuerte(): analiza la contraseña generada y devuelve un booleano si es fuerte
>     (True) o no (False). Una contraseña es fuerte si tiene más de 2 mayúsculas, más
>     de 1 minúscula, más de 2 números y 1 símbolo. (30 puntos)
> - Crear una lista con 4 contraseñas seguras e imprimirlas. (10 puntos)

Ya hice la primera parte pero no sé cómo "analizar la contraseña" para determinar si es fuerte o no. La verdad esa parte es que no he entendido.

Este es mi código:

```
def GenerarPassword(size=10, chars=string.ascii_uppercase
                                  +string.ascii_lowercase
                                  +string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

print(GenerarPassword(10))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola. Las preguntas que son ejercicios no son bien vistas, salvo que agregues el codigo que hayas hecho hasta ahora y digas donde tienes problemas.

Comment: Para analizar la contraseña simplemente recorrela caracter a caracter y ve sumando según condiciones. Si al final todas las condiciones se cumplen pues es fuerte y sino, no.

Comment: En primer lugar debes corregir tu rutina `GenerarPassword` ya que no estaría generando contraseñas con caracteres especiales. Luego para verificar si se dan las condiciones, simplemente recorres la cadena de la password caracter por caracter y verificas cada condición solicitada y la vas sumando, por último verificas dichas sumas para ver si cumplen las condiciones pedidas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo crearía una función que evalue si el string de la contraseña tiene al menos una letra mayúscula, al menos una letra minúscula, al menos un número, al menos un símbolo, etc...

```
def sec(pw):
    for i in list(map(chr, range(65, 91))):  may=i in pw
    for i in list(map(chr, range(97, 123))): min=i in pw
    for i in list(map(chr, range(48, 58))):  num=i in pw
    for i in list(map(chr, range(32, 48))):  sim=i in pw
    nivel=0
    if may: nivel+=1
    if min: nivel+=1
    if num: nivel+=1
    if sim: nivel+=1
    return nivel

contra = GenerarPassword(<argumentos>)
print("El nivel de seguridad de la contraseña es "+str(sec(contra)))
```

**Nota:** si usas python 2.X puedes eliminar la función list()

Luego puedes hacer que según el nivel de seguridad te diga 'fuerte', 'debil', etc, o poner una barrita o lo que tu quieras.

Answer (score 1):

Otra variación es recorrer la contraseña comprobando que tipo de carácter es,
almacenando la cantidad en una variable por tipo de caracter (minúscula, mayúscula, número y símbolo) cuando terminemos de recorrer la contraseña, verificamos que tenga las exigencias que tu dices.

Una vez verificado, si cumple, devuelve "true" o evidentemente si no cumple, devuelve "false"

```
def es_fuerte(contraseña):
    mayus = 0
    minus = 0
    numeros = 0
    simbolos = 0
    for e in contraseña:
        abecedario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
        abecedarioMayus = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        num = "123456789"
        simb = "!@#~€%$·&/()=?¿*^¨-.:,;<>{}"

        if e in abecedarioMayus:
            mayus += 1
        elif e in abecedario:
            minus += 1
        elif e in num:
            numeros += 1
        elif e in simb:
            simbolos += 1

        continue

    if mayus > 2 and minus > 1 and numeros > 2 and simbolos > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Recuerda que los requisitos dados son específicos, es decir, debe tener 3 mayúsculas o mas, 2 minúsculas o mas, 3 números o mas y 2 símbolos o más.